# C, generalize functions argument's type

Tags: c

I was writing a c library for linked lists and trees and i was looking for a solution to generalize the data type handled by these libraries without making a list/tree library for each type i need to handle.

For example, my list library has these functions:

```
/* list.h */
typedef int list_element; // <-- need to generalize that

 struct list_node {   
  list_element value;    
  struct list_node* next;
};

typedef struct list_node list_node;
typedef struct list_node* list;

extern list list_cons(list_element d, list l)
```

And then my list.c:

```
/* list.c */
#include <list.h>

list list_cons(list_element d, list l){
    list m = malloc(sizeof(list_node));
    m->value = element_copy(d);
    m->next = l;
    return m;
}
```

Now suppose that in my main program i've to use a list of int and a list of double, i should create 2 couple of file, something like list_float.c/.h and list_int.c/.h
Also some `list_element` can be struct and need functions like copy/isLess/isEqual to compare themselves
I want to write something like this in my code:

```
/* main.c */
list_cons(void *data, list l);
```

Where `data` is a pointer to any type i want and inside `list_cons`, `element_copy` work for any type of data i pass (obviously i need to copy the data not the pointer to data, void* is the only idea i had to generalize the argument's type of a function)

Comment: basically you want to typedef int list_element then typedef float list_element? No, you can't do this.

Comment: you can do this but you can't use this in one program

Comment: @purec i know i can't, that's the problem. if in my main i've to use different lists with different type, i've to create a library for each type and also use different names for each function, and it's too much pain. I was looking for a solution to avoid this

Comment: you can try to use pointers which can be typecasted easily instead of types int, float. void* data for example

Comment: @purec yes, but look at my example code and read my question. I need also to compare or copy these data. If my data is a struct (for example) i use void* and list.c have no clue about how to handle it.

Comment: If you use C++, this can be done easily with templates.

Comment: @dbush can't, i've to use C, i know there is templates and namespaces that make life really easier, but i'm writing these libs for a school exam, where we are just allowed to use C

Comment: You can make two fields: one for int, one for float. (Pain is unavoidable in any case.)

Comment: @purec no, then every function than handle list doesn't know which field they have to look at

Comment: You can (but probably shouldn't!) use macros to create function names that embed the type information, and then instantiate those macros for the types you need – a poor man's template system.  So you might end up with `list_int_cons()` for `int` type elements, and `list_dbl_cons()` for `double` and so on.  It tends to get ugly rather quickly; it is probably better to avoid the technique.

Answer (score 4):

As a general suggestion, you should not assume that `list_cons` would be the only way to construct a linked list. Sometimes `malloc` is just not available or user wants to preallocate everything in a static array or wants to use custom allocator or...

As a concrete sample, you may look at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h.

If you want other license for your code, search for data structure implementations in xBSD Unix sources.

The general idea is that you only require a linked list structure to contain next/prev and similar fields, not limiting user to your type names. All iterations and basic operations are defined as preprocessor macros, on top of which you implement complex algorithms.

Comment: list and list_cons was just and example for concretize my problem. Had the same problem with other data structure. But thank you, i'll look more deep into macros, maybe i can find a solution and/or understand better linked list in linux

Comment: @LucaLumetti The idea of the Linux implementation is really simple. You have some kind of a `struct list_head { struct list_head *next; };`, you embed it in some struct with your data, and then do stuff with the heads without minding the containers. If you need the container, you get it with the `container_of` macro which is basically the inverse of the standard `offsetof()` macro. But then linked lists are really simple too and this `list_head` abstraction might not be even worth it (IMO).

Comment: @PSkocik yeah, got the idea. i was writing these libs for an university exam and during lessons we always define list as a `struct node { struct node* next, element value }`, then had to use 3 list of 3 different struct in a problem, first thing i thought was just ctrl+c and ctrl+v code for a list in 3 different libs (like structA_list.c/.h, structB_list.c/.h, structC_list.c/.h) and change the type for every list, then i also had to change functions name and code start to look really bad. So i was looking for a solution that doesn't go too far from what professor taught us

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in C11 (read its standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and some [C reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c)) different types can be handled differently (see its §6.5.2).

In particular, the implementation can handle `int`, `double` and pointer values differently (their size and [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) is often different, see [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) & [`alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types)), and some [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) conventions decide that they are passed in different registers (e.g. in function calls).

So you cannot write something which handles (portably) all of `int`, `double` etc... the same way (unless you have [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) functions; with `<stdarg.h>`)

You might decide to implement some "generic" list whose content is some arbitrary pointer. But then you need some *conventions* about them (who is allocating that pointer, who is freeing it, perhaps what operations are allowed, etc...). Look into [Glib doubly-linked lists](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html) for inspiration.

You could also use preprocessor techniques to generate an [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) (of your list) and functions implementing it, given some type name for the content. Look into [SGLIB](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/) for inspiration.

You could also use some [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) techniques: you'll describe somehow the type of the element, and you feed that description into your metaprogram which is some C code generator. Look into [SWIG](http://swig.org/) for inspiration. The generated C code would implement your list's abstract data type.

Don't forget memory [management issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) and describe and document clearly your conventions around them. Read about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).

Think also of complex cases like some list of list of strings (perhaps dynamically allocated à la [strdup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) or obtained using [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)). You'll discover that things are not simple, and you'll need to *explicit* conventions (e.g. could some string be *shared* between two sublists? When would that string be `free`-d, ...).

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good place to use a union.

You can define your base datatype as a union of the most common types you want to support.  Then you would define a enum of the types in question as use that value to flag what the union contains.

```
enum element_type {
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_DOUBLE
};

typedef union {
    int e_int;
    double e_double;
} list_element;

struct list_node {   
  enum element_type type;
  list_element value;    
  struct list_node* next;
};
```

Then you add to the list like this:

```
list list_cons(list_element d, enum element_type type, list l){
    list m = malloc(sizeof(list_node));
    m->type = type;
    m->value = element_copy(d);
    m->next = l;
    return m;
}
```