# Is it better to use a void pointer or a union to create a generic linked list in C?

Tags: c, performance, linked-list, void-pointers

As a little exercise, I tried to create a library to create generic linked list in C. I stumbled across a website (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generic-linked-list-in-c-2/) that used a void pointer to store the data in the struct. My first idea was to use a union structure to account for the different data types (int, char, pointers, etc.) as it is used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1131335/9478236) to another question regarding linked lists with different data types.

I am now wondering what the specific benefits of using the void pointer or a union are, especially performancewise. And also if it really is viable to use the void pointer since our professor told us that we should not work with the void pointer too often as it is very hard to handle (or is this just an advice for unexperienced students?).

Answer (score 2):

When we say a generic list in C, we expect to be implemented with void pointers.

Unions aren't that generic. You say that you would account for different data types, you only refer to four of them, and then say "etc.". That "etc" hides many types, and I bet you wouldn't go about defining a union with all the possible types, right?

So, I wouldn't care about performance here, but about whether my list should be really generic or not.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are doing. The advantage of the union is that the value is contained within the node. This means that you don't have to deal with more allocation. The disadvantage is that you can only store things as large as the union. If you are really trying to make the library flexible, you may at some point want to store a struct in it. In this case, you'll need to use the (void) pointers.

Comment: +1. Or he can use the Linux / https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182653/viktor-latypov approach of an intrusive linked list based on embedding a `struct list_head` as described in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50552376/1084774 answer to a very similar question.