# Abstract Data Structures - Immutability and Cleanup in C

Tags: c, data-structures

Suppose we have a tree data structure:

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

#include <stdarg.h>

typedef struct tree {
  char *tag;
  struct tree **children;
  int num_children;
} tree;

tree *leaf(char *tag);

tree *node(char *tag, int num_children, ...);

#endif
```

With this, we can define a tree in the following, syntactically pleasing way:

```
#include "tree.h"

int main() {

  tree *test =
        node("Tywin", 2, 
            node("Cersei", 2,
                leaf("Joffrey"), 
                leaf("Tommen")
            ),
            leaf("Tyrion")
        );
  return 0;
}
```

Now, I have thought of two possible ways we could implement this. When we define nodes and leaves, we could just copy all the data, as follows:

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

tree *leaf(char *tag) {
  tree *res = malloc(sizeof(*res));
  size_t tag_length = strlen(tag) + 1;
  res->tag = malloc(tag_length * sizeof((*res->tag)));
  strcpy(res->tag, tag);
  res->children = NULL;
  res->num_children = 0;
  return res;
}

tree *node(char *tag, int num_children, ...) {
  tree *res = malloc(sizeof(*res));
  size_t tag_length = strlen(tag) + 1;
  res->tag = malloc(tag_length * sizeof((*res->tag)));
  strcpy(res->tag, tag);
  
  res->children = malloc(num_children * sizeof(*res->children));

  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, num_children);
  tree *current_child;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_children; ++i) {
    *(res->children + i) = malloc(sizeof(**(res->children + i)));
    current_child = va_arg(ap, tree *);
    memcpy(*(res->children + i), current_child, sizeof(*current_child));
  }
  va_end(ap);
  res->num_children = num_children;
  return res;
}
```

But with this, the intermediary calls to `node` (like the ones creating Tyrion and Cersei) create memory leaks. Additionally, even if you could somehow clean up the leaks, you're potentially allocating far more memory than you 'should' be. So the obvious alternative to just to copy the pointers:

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

tree *leaf(char *tag) {
  tree *res = malloc(sizeof(*res));
  res->tag = tag;
  res->children = NULL;
  res->num_children = 0;
  return res;
}

tree *node(char *tag, int num_children, ...) {
  tree *res = malloc(sizeof(*res));
  res->tag = tag;
  
  res->children = malloc(num_children * sizeof(*res->children));

  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, num_children);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_children; ++i) {
    *(res->children + i) = va_arg(ap, tree *);
  }
  va_end(ap);
  res->num_children = num_children;
  return res;
}
```

You could then define a recursive cleanup method that you call on your top-level objects once you've finished (i.e. recursively `free`ing and setting to `NULL` pointers, so if something is `free`d twice, you should be fine). But my concern with this is that you're hoping the user won't change the underlying data later on i.e. there are no guarantees this data structure is immutable.

**Questions:**

1. Is the second approach the canonical way of defining abstract data structures in C?
2. Can I adjust the code at all to give some sort of immutability assurance?

Comment: You also need to store the number of children in the node. (and: varargs is not a good idea, IMHO)

Comment: @wildplasser Good spot - made the change. What's a better alternative to varargs? Just passing a pointer instead?

Comment: Varargs is foundational to supporting the call syntax described.  You cannot get the same without it, though you could get similar, especially by leveraging (possibly variadic) macros.

Comment: Going out of your way to support the "syntactically pleasing" way of constructing trees is probably counterproductive, because there are few applications for it outside testing your code.  It is rare that an application requiring a tree data structure can embed all the wanted data for a (sub)tree in the program source.  Real-world programs almost invariably obtain the data from an external source, at runtime.  And if supporting the inline definition syntax creates design problems then I just don't see how it's worth the effort.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So the above example is a reduced version of what I'm trying to do. Suppose the tree structure above was the primary object of interest in an API. Then I feel the syntactic convenience becomes worth it. Additionally, notation like the above is certainly common in open source projects written in languages with RAII semantics. Is the above way of doing things un-C-like?

Comment: @steeps, I didn't say that trying to provide for such syntax is wrong, only that it is not worth going out of your way -- by which I mean it is not worth investing significant programming effort or design effort, nor should it be a driver for other aspects of your API design.  Focus on how to do what you need without, and add that on afterward if you can do so cheaply.  And indeed, the approach is *not* typical for C APIs, which rarely make much use of variadic functions, and which tend to favor procedural programming styles over functional styles.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok, that's helpful to know - thank you for your guidance!

Comment: And I am by no means convinced that the convenience afforded by such notation would be worth it in practice.  To the extent that tree data structures make sense for your application in the first place, I am still inclined to think that your data generally will not be embedded into programs, but rather obtained from external sources, for which case your nested-construction notation is useless.

Comment: With all that said, however, you may want to look into *compound literals* as an alternative or supplement to constructor-like functions.  Do be sure you understand their semantics before deciding to rely on them, but they might address at least some of your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What you have defined can be called an "intrusive" data structure, because you store the hierarchy data (`children`) along with the payload (`tag`) in each `tree` instance. There is hardly any "canonical" way of defining such a structure - the definition usually depends on the requirements. Some textbooks and open libraries may define tress exactly in this way, some code may provide a custom memory allocators to keep allocated nodes close to each other in memory.

Considering other options, it is preferred to separate node payload and actual hierarchy data. For example, if your tree is only a (complete) binary tree, you can get away with storing node's left/right sibling indices in an array and avoid allocations/pointers altogether. If you need k-ary trees without too much node insertions/deletions, you can look at the [LCRS tree representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree) to represent hierarchy and store all the data associated to node (tags and whatever else) in a separate location.

There is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50552376/1182653) to a seemingly similar question about a simpler data structure. You may take a look at it.

That said, you representation (given the absence of bugs and a correct recursive `cleanup` routine) is a valid tree representation in C.

2. In C you have an option to lock everything down or apply something like a Copy-on-Write strategy while modifying your trees. It all depends on requirements, once again. Do you have to search the tree, do you frequently update the structure or only recalculate/reassign node data ? Do you process this data locally using CPUs only or you need to share the tree with GPU/DSP or transfer it over the network ? These questions may help you to select *the* representation and synchronization primitives required. Otherwise, there is no "standard" way to "make everything thread-safe/immutable" once and use all the time. One suggestion I may have is when using the LCRS, you can program in a "functional way" and "calculate" the new hierarchy array from an old one each time you need to modify the tree structure.